# How to store and query spatial data on Azure Table Service

Tags: azure, geospatial, azure-table-storage

I am trying to create a location based app where people can query the records created within 5 miles of their location.

When the record is created, I will store the Latitude and Longitude in the Azure Table Service.

Once I have this data, how do I fetch all the records within 5 miles from my current location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Azure Table Storage queries to be optimized, they'll need to run on the Partition Key and the Row Key. A solution could be to store the latitude in the Partition Key and the longitude in the RowKey. The Partition Key and Row Key combinations need to be unique (think primary key in SQL). I would use this strategy and if you have multiple entries for the same latitude and longitude, then you could use ATS' dynamic properties or InsertOrMerge to store them in the same row. That way you could query like this:

```
IQueryable<Entries> query = 
(from q in _table.CreateQuery<Entries>()
where q.PartitionKey.CompareTo(minLatitude) > 0
&& q.PartitionKey.CompareTo(maxLatitude) < 0
&& q.RowKey.CompareTo(minLongitude) > 0
&& q.RowKey.CompareTo(maxLongitude) < 0
select q);
```

You could also get clever with the PartitionKey and use it to store a range of latitudes or regions in order to limit the # of partitions needed. SQL Azure also supports [geospatial queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just doing work in this area and found that Azure Search will provide geospatial searches over Azure Table Storage. One setback is that the smallest scale beyond the developer sandbox is $200 per month - well worth the money for a commercial venture but rather high for small operations.

In order to make this work I needed to duplicate the Latatitude and Longitude fields into the GeoJson format, ie.

{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]}

The free developer search option will allow one datasource based on partition key. For the purposes of my testing I have a table with everything in the same partition and unique RowKeys. I indexed the RowKey and the GeoJson value and found it works very well to search for all records within a radius of a given point.

While this is great, I think there or other storage solutions that will work better. DocumentDb and SqlAzure both support geospatial queries and, given the combination of the cost of storage and search, the cost of these alternatives is attractive.